# jQuery - Check if child div is visible

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to see if the the child div of an li is visible and if so apply a class to the li. This is what I got but it's not working.

```
if(jQuery('#menu li').children('div').css('display') != 'none') {
    jQuery('li', this).addClass('dropHover');
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the DOM structure? and the full code can help, because that `this` might be wrong. what does it refer to?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if (jQuery('#menu li > div').is(':visible')){
    //...
    jQuery('li', this).addClass('dropHover');
}
```

I don't know what is the DOM structure or to what `this` refers to, but this might do the trick as well:

```
jQuery('#menu li:has(div:visible)').addClass('dropHover');
```

It adds the class "dropHover" to all `<li>` elements that have a visible `<div>`
and they need to be children of an element with the menu id.