# Check if DIV is visible or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div name `uploadBiodata_manual_+(count)`.within that div i have a file type input with id '`file_uploadBiodata_manual_+(count)`'.Here how to check div is visible or not.?and if div is visible how to check the file type input has file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406094/jquery-check-if-child-div-is-visible it will help you.... its with jQuery

Comment: Guys, he asked for pure javascript... So he's not using jQuery.

Comment: i am using display: none;

Comment: Well then just do `document.getElementById("myElement").style["display"] == "none";`

Comment: yes it works.but how i wil get whether the file type has file?

Answer (score 6):

you could just check for div display property along with input file type's value property, like:

```
if(document.getElementById("your_div_id").style.display != "none") {
    //its visible
   //check if input fie type has file selected
   if(document.getElementById("your_file_input_id").value != "") {
       //its has file selected
   } 
}
```

Comment: What if the parent is the one that has the visibility none

Answer (score 2):

check clientHeight. It will be zero for invisible elements

```
 isVisible=function(elemID){
    var e=document.getElementById(elemID);
    if(!e) return false;            //Not exisiting
    if (e.clientHeight) return true;        //Height of invisible components are zero
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution...

```
var isVisible = $('#dvData').is(':visible');
alert("dvData is " + isVisible);
```

Comment: Nobody asked for jQuery!! And please learn to format code in answers properly and add more of an explanation than 'try this...'